# Mysql table lock aliasing not working

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a scheduling table which I need to lock then read from. I am currently trying to do this:

```
LOCK TABLES db.schedule AS j_read READ;

SELECT * FROM db.schedule as j_read;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

When I run this I get the error:

> Error Code: 1100. Table 'j_read' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

I've gone over the mysql table locks documentation [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html) but i cant figure our why this is not working for me. if i don't alias anything it works like this

```
LOCK TABLES db.schedule READ;

SELECT * FROM db.schedule;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Any ideas why this is not working or how to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way to make this work. Need to obtain a lock for both the alias name and the table itself

```
LOCK TABLES db.schedule READ,db.schedule AS j_read READ;

SELECT * FROM db.schedule as j_read;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this chunk of documentation, you still need to select from table but reference your lock alias. You're looking for last line.

```
mysql> LOCK TABLE t AS myalias READ;
mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
ERROR 1100: Table 't' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
mysql> SELECT * FROM t AS myalias;
```

Comment: Sorry i missed that in my post, that's actually what i did and it still throws me the same error. See the updated version now